# Will internal data are copied on broadcasting in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

In my understanding, numpy broadcasting just modifies shape and strides internally, and never touches internal data (raw array). For example,

```
>>> a = np.arange(1, 9).reshape(2, 4)
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8]])
>>> a.shape
(2, 4)
>>> a.strides
(32, 8)
>>> # broadcast
>>> np.broadcast_to(a, (2, 2, 4))
array([[[1, 2, 3, 4],
        [5, 6, 7, 8]],

       [[1, 2, 3, 4],
        [5, 6, 7, 8]]])
>>> np.broadcast_to(a, (2, 2, 4)).shape
(2, 2, 4)
>>> np.broadcast_to(a, (2, 2, 4)).strides
(0, 32, 8)
```

above shows that after broadcasting `a` to (2, 2, 4) 3D array, the 0 is pushed to strides. This works as broadcasting without modifying (copying) actual data.

However, the `nbytes` looks also changed after broadcasting. See:

```
>>> a.nbytes
64
>>> np.broadcast_to(a, (2, 2, 4)).nbytes
128
```

Does this `nbytes` change means the actual data is also copied? Or just showing pseudo byte count?

Comment: `nbytes` is derived from shape and dtype, not a 'count' of the databuffer size.  Another thing to look at is a.base` (and after broadcast_to).  Also `a.__array_interface__`

Comment: Thank you, `base` and `__array_interface__` works.

Comment: Just try `x=np.broadcast_to(a, (1000000, 1000000, 2, 4); x.nbytes`. Do you have 64 terabytes of memory on your machine? I don't, and yet, no swap, no sweat. I have this nbytes=64000000000000 array that I can play with. `x[123456,234567,:,:].sum()` is 36 for example (as any `x[*,*,:,:].sum()` obviously). Just to be sure it is not some "allocate/copy only when used" thing

Answer (score 0):

The value of `nbytes` [is defined](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/294657702ea00f832cbe6b1f64133ab8debc0b24/numpy/_core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h#L79) as `item_size * number_of_items`:

```
#define PyArray_NBYTES(m) (PyArray_ITEMSIZE(m) * PyArray_SIZE(m))
```

That is, `nbytes` doesn't return the size of the memory allocated for the array, but rather *a pseudo byte count*, if you will.

With some caution, we can try `np.multiply(arr.strides, arr.shape).max()` or `lambda arr: arr.nbytes if arr.base is None else arr.base.nbytes` to estimate the allocated memory. But these may not work well with some weird constructions, for example produced by [as_strided](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html). So, to estimate the actual memory span covered by the array, maybe it's better to use the formula `itemsize + max_shift`, where maximum shift is equal to `sum((shape - 1)*strides)`:

```
span = lambda x: x.itemsize + np.dot(x.shape, x.strides) - np.sum(x.strides)
```

As an illustration:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

foo = np.arange(5)
bar = as_strided(foo, shape=(2, 2), strides=(2*foo.itemsize, 2*foo.itemsize))

mem_span = lambda arr: arr.itemsize + np.dot(arr.shape, arr.strides) - np.sum(arr.strides)

print(
    f'{foo=}'
    , f'{bar=}'
    , f'{bar.itemsize=}'
    , f'{bar.nbytes=}'
    , f'{mem_span(bar)=}'
    , sep='\n'
)

# foo=array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4])
# bar=array([[0, 2],
#            [2, 4]])
# bar.itemsize=8
# bar.nbytes=32
# mem_span(bar)=40

a = np.arange(1, 9).reshape(2, 4)
b = np.broadcast_to(a, (2, 2, 4))

print(
    f'{a.base=}'
    , f'{mem_span(a.base)=}'
    , f'{mem_span(a)=}'
    , f'{mem_span(b)=}'
    , sep='\n'
)

# a.base=array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
# mem_span(a.base)=64
# mem_span(a)=64
# mem_span(b)=64
```